# Visual Studio Code with GO - Multiple main declarations (launch settings)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS code and Golang.
I have an existing project containing 2 different services - let's call one A and the second one B.
Both A and B sits under the same directory.

Whenever I try to run A or B, I get the following error :

```
# directory/directory/directory/A&B_Directory
./A.go:12:6: main redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./B.go:18:6
```

I tried playing with the `launch.json` file, adding the following sections :

```
   {
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "program": "FullDirectory/A.go"
    }
```

Also tried in the program attribute to set to `${file}` and many other variations that failed.

I'd love for some direction, I'm kinda lost.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't have more than one `main` in a single program. All files in a directory are part of the same package. If you want A and B to be separate "services", they need to live in different directories.

Comment: It's not a single program, it's 2 different programs sitting under the same directory. In Goland you can have configuration profiles for each service.

Comment: Then how come it works with Goland?

Comment: It doesn't. I assure you.

Comment: One directory, one package. Never more. That simple. No reason to argue here.

Comment: Ok saying stuff like that isn't helping.
In Goland you have the option to choose what file to run.
I'm pretty sure it's possible to choose that also in VS code.

Comment: I have both Goland and VS code on machine - and it works with goland. You can't argue with that.

Comment: @DotnetProg I have a vague feeling that you might be bit by having a habit of using `go run file1 [file2 [...]]` to do compile&run rounds outside of vscode.  The "problem" is that it's a "degraded" case not normally used for "real" Go projects. When working on a project "the regular way", you typically do `go install [package_spec]` which either uses *the whole* current directory or walks a tree of them speficied by `package_spec`, builds and installs everything there which is not up-to-date. *This* won't work with two files in the same difectory both containing `main()` in package "main".

Comment: @DotnetProg, …so it may well be the case then when you hit whatever stands for "run" in vscode, it really attempts to do something akin to `go install`, and fails.

Comment: VSCode does `go build` then runs the executable, which is what an IDE *should* do. Gogland is probably doing `go run`, which is a terrible practice, and should be avoided - one reason being that it masks exactly these kinds of issues, where you have an invalid package with multiple `main` declarations in one package.

Comment: @DotnetProg JFTR you might find these [two](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/04/what-does-go-build-build) short [posts](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/01/21/using-go-test-build-and-install) to be of interest as they basically serve as a quick intro to what `go` tool can do with the Go code.

Comment: @kostix and Adrian Thanks a lot for all the information and people who tried to help. I'll look into it later on today. In the meanwhile, I decided not to waste anymore time on VS code for now, I'll go with Gogland for now, and when I have more time (and experience with go) I'll try to get my project to work with VS code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: **this is not the recommended approach**, I agree with others, you shall separate the *service* A and B into different directory.

Answer to your question: To launch a specific file, use the following configuration to emulate `go run current-file`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run current file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "exec",
            "program": "full-path-to-go.exe",
            "args": ["run", "${file}"],
            "showLog": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Mode `exec` is for launching pre-built binary given in the property `program` (you must specify full path to `go` binary). Then as the arguments, just add `run` and filename (`${file}`) to property `args`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, tried to get this configuration to work but no success. In the meanwhile - I'll just go with Gogland, and look into your answer more thoroughly when I have more experience with Go.

Comment: @DotnetProg, What was the error? I've tried it, and it works. You have to open and view the file that you want to run.

Comment: I confirm this work, vscode 1.67.2,   `Delve Debugger Version: 1.9.0 Build: $Id: 69310c2f438e492f892d6af22e8e62c8ea1e9d8d`

Comment: sample log config
    `Config: {"name":"Launch Package","type":"go","request":"launch","mode":"debug","program":".","args":["run","/src/golang/body.go"],"env":{"GOPATH":"/root/go"},"trace":"verbose","logOutput":"debugger,dap","__configurationTarget":5,"packagePathToGoModPathMap":{"/src/golang":"/src/golang"},"debugAdapter":"dlv-dap","showRegisters":false,"showGlobalVariables":false,"substitutePath":[],"showLog":false,"dlvFlags":[],"hideSystemGoroutines":false,"dlvToolPath":"/root/go/bin/dlv","__buildDir":"/src/golang"}`