# golang build -i -a fails (permission denied)

Tags: ubuntu, go, build, goland

I am a go newbie.

I have installed golang 1.9 from the official binary distribution on my ubuntu. I have also installed the Gogland IDE.

When I try to debug the simplest go program ("hello world") using Gogland, I get the following error:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
GOPATH=/home/user/go
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -i -o /tmp/defaultgo -gcflags "-N -l" -a /home/user/go/src/hello/hello.go
go install runtime/internal/sys: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/internal/sys.a: permission denied
```

When trying to build from the command line (not using Gogland), I noticed that I get the same error whenever I am using the `-i -a` switches.

Comment: 1. Never ever set GOROOT. Never. No diskussion here. 2. Probably just don't use -a. 3. Use the official installation from golang.org, not from Ubuntu.

Comment: @Volker 1. I did not set GOROOT. Perhaps gogland does it for you when you choose an SDK (I can't run a program withut choosing an SDK)? 2. It seems gogland uses -a by default. How can I change that? 3. I used the official gogland distribution (tar.gz downloaded from golang.org)

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46050568/720999).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: EAP 13 was just released and it fixes this specific problem. Please see: https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2017/09/04/gogland-eap-13-better-completion-new-inspections-fixed-performance-bugs-and-more/

Original:

This happens because of upgraded support from Delve for Go 1.9 projects.

The latest version of Delve will use `-a` in order to recompile all transitive dependencies and ensure none of them are included with their optimized versions instead of the debugging friendly ones so that it can remove a lot of potential bugs.

You can remove the `-i` flag so that the dependencies are not installed, which shouldn't cause the error anymore.

This will be improved hopefully in Go 1.10 as there are changes depending on the Go team.

Hope this explains the issue, if not, please see the discussion here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4382

Edit: this will be addressed in the EAP 13, which is bound to be released very soon, see the tracking issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4430 as it contains additional details regarding this problem

Answer (score 0):

The `-a` command-line option tells the `go` tool to rebuild *"everything* Go", and this includes the Go standard library and even the Go runtime itself—that stuff linked to each Go program which actually implements goroutines and all the interesting bits.

Since you have Go installed into a location not normally writable by end users (`/usr/local/go`), an attempt to recompile and update files there (`/usr/local/go/pkg`) rightfully fails with "permission denied".

The main takeaway is that there is exactly zero cases you'd need to pass `-a` to `go build` until you very well understand what you want to achieve, and this will come quite later in your learning curve ;-)

So please do what @Volker said:

- Don't set `GOROOT`.
- Don't use `-a` with `go build`.

Also condier using `go install` instead of `go build` — for the reasons
explained [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/04/what-does-go-build-build).

Comment: I did not set GOROOT. I only chose the SDK in gogland. It seems gogland uses the -a switch by default (why?), and I am nut sure how to control it.

Comment: @MarkM, based on the comment thread to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45961085/720999), I'd probably recommend to drop Goglang for a while -- until its authors at least learn how Go projects are supposed to be built properly.

Consider trying vscode or something lighter like LiteIDE.

Note that you can work with Go just fine from popular text editors (Vim, Emacs) inclduding hipster things like Sublime.

Comment: @kostix there are a number of reasons why the IDE does what it does.

For GOROOT, it needs to do that because you can actually configure it to use different Go versions for different projects, regardless of the configuration you have in your system.

For go build -a, this is done in order to help delve get better debugging information and it wasn't possible to to do reliably until Go 1.9. Any editor using delve debug package/name will automatically do so under the hood without you knowing what's happening.

So please stop mocking things you do not understand.

Comment: @dlsniper, thanks for your insight. I disagree on the need of setting `GOROOT` though: recent (that is, 1.4+, I reckon) versions of Go figure out `GOROOT` just out of the location of their `go` binary, so it's perfectly okay to run something like `~/devel/golang1.9/bin/go env` and see it having set `GOROOT` to `~/devel/golang1.9/` all by itself.

Comment: Go 1.9 changed how it detects where Go is installed, not Go 1.4, making GOROOT less needed. However, there's no control over the user environment or the way go was installed. For example you can still unpack the Go 1.8 tarball from the website and it will want Go to be in /usr/local/go If by any chance it's there, it will use that. For Windows it's the same / worse as Go really doesn't play nice in a multi-version setup there. Even so, users might have that variable set, but maybe to a different location and so on. Hope this helps understanding the complexities behind this choice.